# Menu items missing admin template AdminLTE in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, adminlte

I have just installed admin panel "AdminLTE" by following this [tutorial](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel). It is successfully installed but with an exception, i.e. the menu items are not the same as they are shown on their official website.

Please view the attached screenshots:

My Case: (with missing menu items):

[image]

Official (with complete menu items):

[image]

Comment: Have you error with icons? Or dropdown menu exception? What exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 2nd screenshot is just the demo page, after installation the sidebar.blade.php just contains the values as shown in the 1st screenshot.

As you followed the tutorial there should exist a sidebar.blade.php in resources/views/vendor/adminlte/layouts/partials/ where you can edit this sidebar.